# Can't Change Beamer Poster Size

Tags: beamer, beamerposter, posters, size

I had made a beamer poster. Turns out I need to change its size.

Nothing I am doing is helping me. This is the exact poster I am using, https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/landscape-beamer-poster-template/vjpmsxxdvtqk#

I wanted to change its size to 76.2 x 76.2 cm.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[size=custom,width=76.2,height=76.2,scale=1.25]{beamerposter}

%\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\usetheme{confposter} % Use the confposter theme supplied with this template
```

Please help me know how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question.

Comment: @samcarter oh I have provided..the link is the exact latex code on overleaf

Comment: @samcarter it is the same case, i want to change its size..just open the template and the poster opens up with latex code

Comment: Please add a MWE directly to your question - otherwise this questions depends on the validity of your link and in case the link breaks it become useless for future visitors of this site.

Comment: @samcarter okay, let me see how to prepare..I have sty files in the poster as well..plus overleaf is quite famous..any solutions for the problem, i have tried many solutions like setting paperwidth and height separately..etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the part of the code you don't show in your question, your template hard codes the page size. If you comment these two lines you get a 76.2 x 76.2 cm page.

It is also unnecessary to load the `graphicx` package with beamer.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[size=custom,width=76.2,height=76.2,scale=1.25]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{confposter} 

%\setlength{\paperwidth}{48in} % A0 width: 46.8in
%\setlength{\paperheight}{36in} % A0 height: 33.1in

%\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{title}
\author{author names}
\date{date}
\institute{institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```